# sandbox.jar file for itext5?

Tags: java, eclipse, itext

From where do I get the sandbox.jar file for itext5? I searched many places and got some of the but none of them are the ones with classes like "WrapToTest" or "xmlworker".Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

The sandbox is a place that we use to "play". In the sandbox, you will find many different, short standalone examples. It doesn't make sense to deploy all of these examples in production. I can't think of any use case that would require such a jar, hence we don't release one.

However, as you have noticed, we do use the examples in our QA environment. Most of the examples are automatically used as a test. For this to work, we also need plenty of `cmp_xyx.pdf` files. In the test environment, each example is executed, producing a PDF that is then compared with the `cmp` file, using iText (structural comparison) as well as third party tools (GhostScript, ImageMagick for a pixel by pixel comparison).

We use these tests (and tools) internally. You have access to the code through GitHub, but we don't create a release, nor do we distribute the full test suite (among others, because there are third party tools involved).

If you really want to get a jar, it's really simple: get the code from GitHub, and run Maven `install`. A jar file will be generated in the `target` directory. If you want to run the test, you will have to download the required third party tools from their original location.

**Update:** upon reading your question a second time,  I realized that you might be asking for `WrapToTest`, not because you want to run tests, but because you want to execute an example. In that case, it's sufficient to remove all references to `WrapToTest`. Removing those references will it cause the example to produce a different result. It will only prevent that the example will be used as a test (in a test environment).

I also notice that you mention XML Worker. XML Worker is a separate jar that is completely unrelated to the sandbox.

You might say:

> OK, so my question was wrong. I had to ask for XML Worker instead of asking for the sandbox. Can you tell me where to find XML Worker?

I could tell you, but I wouldn't do you a service by doing so, because XML Worker is being discontinued. It has been replaced by [pdfHTML](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML). There was never a good tutorial for XML Worker, but there's a great tutorial that explains how to convert HTML to PDF using iText 7 + pdfHTML: https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml

Up until recently, pdfHTML was only available as a closed source add-on, but now you can also use it under the AGPL open source license (provided that you respect the AGPL).